# How to compute CR between original image and decompressed image?

Tags: performance

I used my code to compute compression ratio .I found my image after compression that has the same dimensions before compression. for example : IM= 512x512 ...after compression IM'=512 x512 is this ok ?
Hint : I used JPEG format.

2- I want to compute compression ratio and I used the reconstruct image to compute it.
is this true or not? or how can I calculate CR between original image and reconstruct image?
Thanks

Comment: Compressing an image **does not change** its size in pixel.

Comment: ok ..but the size of image is changed for example the original image=207kb after compression reconstruct image = 28kb how I can compute CR ?

Answer (score 0):

There are more details [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/237620-how-to-calculate-image-compression-ratio) but with 207 KB reduced to 28 KB the compression ratio is 207/28 (= 7.4) to 1, or `7.4:1` or `7.4/1` or `86.5%` ( 100 x ( 1 - 1÷7.4 ) ).